# UNION operation in Aerospike or Couchbase

Tags: nosql, cassandra, couchbase, aerospike

I am trying to do a UNION operation in Aerospike(No-Sql database). However there is no such operation provided by it's query language.

How we can go for a UNION operation in a No-Sql database like Aerospike. I believe this is also applicable to other NoSql database like Couchbase, as I cannot find a supported construct in them as well.

As an example, Let's say I have a collection {key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3}. I would be interested in getting the set of collections as follows.

```
SELECT * from  namespace.collections where key2 = someValue and key1=someValue
UNION
SELECT * from namespace.collections where key1 = someValue and key3=someValue
```

Comment: union of two different collections/tables?

Comment: yes union of a set of collections from a query

Comment: You need to give more information on your data, provide some examples and it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but can't you just create a view that emits on the value and you pass the 3 keys to filter the view by? If you include the json and the full problem, we can try again.

Comment: I have really not tried on Couchbase, but yes that seems promising. In Aerospike there is no such concept of views and filters on multiples indexes are not working indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Aerospike does not support UNIONs or JOINs natively.
I do not know any NoSQL database which supports this.

Comment: UNION can be done through a UDF on the client-side: http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/udf_guide.html

Answer (score 0):

I first learned about Aerospike after your question, but i'm working with Couchbase for about half a year. If I understood correctly the principle of operation of these databases is the same. We have a very large and non-trivial hashmap and can only perform get and set operations. No UNION, no JOIN, no other relational operations on sets. So, we can only solve this problem on our client side by out custom way. We can get from DB "Bin" or "Json" and combine them in the way we think is right. If you tell us more about your problem, I'll gladly try to help you.

Comment: I am looking at utilizing views/server side scripts to do a map-reduce on server. So, pulling things back to client and doing a union won't work.

Comment: Under the client part I meant API, that you use to interact with your database. You can write your layer between user and server, which will handle the processing of response from DB on user's request.